# Education of Girls/Women

Tags: quran, women, education

The Taliban says that the Quran forbids the education of girls over the age of 8. Is this true? Are they actually quoting the Quran?

Comment: Can you quote their actual statement? The Quran does not directly say anything of the sort. However nine is the minimum age of adulthood for a woman as derived by scholars from ahadith. It is possible that they do not allow for going to schools where women need to go out of their homes and visit, as going out unnecessarily is contrary to the Quranic recommendations. They are not quoting the Quran, but they may be interpreting various Islamic sources.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm just a person who was raised Catholic and I lost my faith long ago. I'm trying to learn more about Islam and the Quran. I'm sorry but I don't have the direct quote from the Taliban. I know that they have definitely destroyed girls' schools in Afghanistan and Pakistan. They also attacked and killed some of the girls that attended those schools. Malala Yousafzai is a prime example. So something about these girls going to school is obviously upsetting them.

Comment: @user39996 I would recommend you to look at the Quran tafseers or hadeeths. instead of look at what some groups did or do! For girls learning

Comment: That is why I am here, to learn the truth instead of the limited information and/or propaganda that the media and government provides. I have come with an open mind. 

Answer (score 1):

As per Hadith seeking knowledge is mandatory for every Muslim. First word Angel Jabriel taught to Prophet Muhammad is 'Iqra', means read, so Quran starts with the instruction to read.
The problem is not education the problem is environment in education institutions which doesn't meet the Quranic criteria of how should girl dress and walk in public. So whats the criteria?

Say to the believing men that: they should cast down their glances and guard their private parts (by being chaste). This is better for them.” Say to the believing women that: they should cast down their glances and guard their private parts (by being chaste)…” (Surah an-Nur Verse 30-31)

Answer (score 1):

عَنْ أَبِي سَعِيدٍ ، جَاءَتِ امْرَأَةٌ إِلَى رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ فَقَالَتْ : يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ، ذَهَبَ الرِّجَالُ بِحَدِيثِكَ، فَاجْعَلْ لَنَا مِنْ نَفْسِكَ يَوْمًا نَأْتِيكَ فِيهِ، تُعَلِّمُنَا مِمَّا عَلَّمَكَ اللَّهُ. فَقَالَ : " اجْتَمِعْنَ فِي يَوْمِ كَذَا وَكَذَا، فِي مَكَانِ كَذَا وَكَذَا ". فَاجْتَمَعْنَ، فَأَتَاهُنَّ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ، فَعَلَّمَهُنَّ مِمَّا عَلَّمَهُ اللَّهُ، ثُمَّ قَالَ : " مَا مِنْكُنَّ امْرَأَةٌ تُقَدِّمُ بَيْنَ يَدَيْهَا مِنْ وَلَدِهَا ثَلَاثَةً، إِلَّا كَانَ لَهَا حِجَابًا مِنَ النَّارِ ". فَقَالَتِ امْرَأَةٌ مِنْهُنَّ : يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ، اثْنَيْنِ ؟ قَالَ : فَأَعَادَتْهَا مَرَّتَيْنِ، ثُمَّ قَالَ : " وَاثْنَيْنِ وَاثْنَيْنِ وَاثْنَيْنِ ".

A woman came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and said: "O Messenger of Allah! Only men benefit from your talks, so please fix a day for us, to teach us the knowledge which Allah has taught you." The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) fixed a day and directed them to assemble. When they gathered, the Prophet (ﷺ) went to them and taught them what Allah had taught him. He (ﷺ) then said, "Any woman of you whose three children die (in infancy) they will be a guard for her against Fire (of Hell)." One of the women asked: "What if she loses two?" The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) replied, "Even two."

This hadeeth shows that the prophet concern about teaching women as much teaching men!

Comment: Thank you for providing these quotes from the Quran. This helps me in my quest to understand Islam.

Comment: It is a hadeeth not a Quran! But since hadeeth from the prophet and he is the one most understand what the Islam is! What it still a holy thing.